# Is there a way to read superscripts from a pdf file in Python?

Tags: python, pypdf

At the moment when I use PyPDF2 to read in a pdf to text in python it convert any superscript to regular text on a newline. Is there any way to convert superscript directly to superscript rather than to regular text.

For example:
This line of text:

```
1¹ ¹ᐟ⁴ 2⁵  3¹  4² 5¹ ¹ᐟ⁴ 6¹  7² ¹ᐟ²
```

gets coverted to:

```
\n1\n11/4\n2\n5\n3\n1\n4\n2\n5\n11/4\n6\n1\n7\n2\n7\n21/2
```

I have created a partial parser to convert it to back to superscript but it would be a lot easier if there was a way to read it directly to superscript.

Comment: There is no "superscript text" in the PDF specifications. There are superscript Unicode characters, but if these numbers were those, you'd have gotten them as such.

Comment: I see, thanks for the insight